# NSDate countdown with NSInterval

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Here's my code:

```
NSDate *currDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *currentTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currDate];

NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
int interval = 1*60; // one minute (minutes*60)
long int nowSeconds = (long int) [now timeIntervalSince1970];
int secondsLeft = interval - (nowSeconds % interval);

NSDate *nextIntervalDate =  [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:nowSeconds+secondsLeft];

NSString *nextTrigger = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:nextIntervalDate];

timeRemaining.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", secondsLeft/60, secondsLeft%60];

NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", currentTime, nextTrigger]);

if ([currentTime isEqualToString:nextTrigger]) {

}
```

Problem is, 'if ([currentTime isEqualToString:nextTrigger])' is never equal. Because nextTrigger changes to the next time segment before they're equal. Here is the NSLog:

```
2013-01-17 15:54:59.987 app[35987:c07] 15:54:59:15:55:00
2013-01-17 15:54:59.997 app[35987:c07] 15:54:59:15:55:00    
2013-01-17 15:55:00.007 app[35987:c07] 15:55:00:15:56:00   <----RIGHT HERE
2013-01-17 15:55:00.016 app[35987:c07] 15:55:00:15:56:00
```

My code's nextTrigger is basically a round up of the current time by the nearest minute. ALSO, this whole code segment is in a repeating NSTimer every .1 seconds.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you explain what your code is supposed to do?

Comment: Basically, when I press a button, it's setting an NSTimer to trigger my code every .1 seconds. It's waiting for the next "round time." Like, if it's 10:31:23 then it'll count down to 10:32:00. If the time was 01:10:01 then it'll count down to 01:11:00

Comment: Then when the count down has ended, if ([currentTime isEqualToString:nextTrigger]), some other code will trigger.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had a somewhat similar problem. What I did was make a copy and check it by that.(one thing is to have both `oldTrigger` and `newTrigger` declared already)Check this code

```
NSDate *currDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *currentTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currDate];

NSDate *now = [NSDate date]; 
int interval = 1*60; // one minute (minutes*60)
long int nowSeconds = (long int) [now timeIntervalSince1970];
int secondsLeft = interval - (nowSeconds % interval);

NSDate *nextIntervalDate =  [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:nowSeconds+secondsLeft];
oldTrigger = nextTrigger;
nextTrigger = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:nextIntervalDate];

timeRemaining.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", secondsLeft/60, secondsLeft%60];

NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", currentTime, nextTrigger]);

if ([currentTime isEqualToString:oldTrigger]) {

}
```

Comment: This causes the app to crash for some reason. Thread1:EXEC_BAD_ACCESS on this line: if ([currentTime isEqualToString:oldTrigger]) {

Comment: Put nextTrigger = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:nextIntervalDate];
before oldTrigger = nextTrigger, and that didn't cause the crash, but alas, oldtrigger and current time are still not equal

Comment: Did this work? The reason they were not equal in the first place was because newTrigger got updated to quick. If this wasn't the error then make sure oldTrigger = nextTrigger is before nextTrigger = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:nextIntervalDate];

Answer (score 0):

If you have code that you'd like triggered when the next whole minute passes, it's inefficient to repeatedly check to see if said time has passed. Put that code in its own method, and create a single NSTimer to trigger it at the appropriate time.

```
NSDate* date = [NSDate date] ;
NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar] ;

NSDateComponents* secondsComponents = [calendar components:NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:date] ;
NSTimeInterval secondsUntilNextWholeMinute = 60 - secondsComponents.second ;
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:secondsUntilNextWholeMinute  target:self  selector:@selector(yourMethod)  userInfo:nil  repeats:NO ] ;
```

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention, I invalidate the NSTimer here if ([currentTime isEqualToString:oldTrigger]) { so it's only happening once. Thanks though!

Comment: What I meant was, instead of having your code run every 0.1 seconds to check if the next whole minute has passed, you can simply tell iOS to run a certain method at a certain time.

Comment: Ah! I like that. Let me try to implement it.